# Difference between (0)* and (0*)*

Tags: regular-languages

I know that,

`0*` generates, `NULL, 0, 00, 000, 0000, ... and so on`.

But how does `(0*)*` actually work? Does it generate even length 0's?

Like this, `NULL, 00, 0000, 000000...`

or it generates strings same as first expression? What I thought is that if it has 2 star means, that it will multiply any string inside, regardless of odd or even length and the output will be even eventually? Am I going correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They generate the same set of strings. In fact, for any set of strings $A$:

$${A^*}^* = A^*$$

I am going to use lower-case lambda $\lambda$ to denote the zero-length string; some textbooks use epsilon: $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$. This is what you called `NULL`, but it is more common to reserve that word for the null set or empty set, usually denoted $\emptyset$.

Intuitively, $A^*$ means $\lambda \cup A \cup AA \cup AAA \cup \cdots$.

Then:

$${A^*}^* = \lambda \cup A^* \cup A^*A^* \cup A^*A^*A^* \cup \cdots$$

We could expand this, but don't have to. What I want you to notice is that there is a set of strings $B$ such that:

$${A^*}^* = A^* \cup B$$

Or, to put it another way, $A^*$ is a *subset* of ${A^*}^*$. Every string in $A^*$ must also be in ${A^*}^*$.

To show that ${A^*}^* = A^*$ would also require showing that ${A^*}^*$ is a subset of $A^*$, and I'll leave that as an exercise if you're interested. But this is enough to show that every string in $\mathbf{0}^*$ is also in ${\mathbf{0}^*}^*$, including those with odd length.

The Kleene star operator is sometimes easier reason about if you use subsets rather than equalities. See [Kleene algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra) for more on this.